# Is this implementation of MSVCRT's wcscpy_s correct?

Tags: c, msvcrt, wstring

Is this implementation of `wcscpy_s` from MSVCRT ([reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/strcpy-s-wcscpy-s-mbscpy-s?view=msvc-170)) correct?

```
errno_t wcscpy_s(
   wchar_t *dest,
   rsize_t dest_size,
   const wchar_t *src
)
{
    if (dest == NULL) {
        return EINVAL;
    }
    if (src == NULL) {
        dest[0] = L'\0';
        return EINVAL;
    }

    size_t src_size = wcsnlen(src, min(dest_size, RSIZE_MAX) - 1) + 1;
    if (dest_size < src_size) {
        dest[0] = L'\0';
        return ERANGE;
    }

    wcsncpy(dest, src, src_size);
    return 0;
}
```

Assume `wcsnlen` and `wcsncpy` to be POSIX conforming. Assume also macros and types to be correctly defined.

The `-1) + 1` is present because `wcslen` expects sizes to not include the terminating null wide character, while `wcscpy_s` and `wcsncpy` sizes do.

Any correction, feedback, or suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Fails to handle `dest_size == 0` correctly in the error handlers.

Comment: Also fails to handle overlap between source and destination. Also fails to handle the case where the source string length changes after the initial `wcsnlen`. Also overfills the output buffer after the terminating null. Finally, note that this would fit better on [codereview.se].

Comment: @RaymondChen thanks. 
1) the behavior of MSVCRT's `wcscpy_s` is undefined if the source and destination strings overlap
2) you're right that my function is not thread safe
3) I changed the `size` parameter of `wcsncpy` to `src_size`. Is it correct now?
Finally, thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @ikegami thanks, but if `dest_size == 0`, then `dest_size < src_size` is true since `src_size` is strictly greater than `0`

Comment: As for `dest_site==0`: `wcscpy_s(buffer, 0, NULL)` overflows the `buffer`. Also, you fail to call the invalid parameter handler when an invalid parameter is encountered. Please don't keep changing the code. That invalidates earlier comments.

Comment: As for `dest_size==0`, the documentation clearly states that `dest[0]` is set to 0 if `src == NULL`, even if `dest_size` is zero. Am I missing something?

Comment: https://github.com/intel/safestringlib/blob/master/safeclib/wcscpy_s.c